# drools linkage error with multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, drools, execute

I have a junit test case which creating two threads to run a application.  In this application, there is a method updateStatus which used for fire drools rules.  And in this rules file, I have some functions like next :

```
function Object updateItem() {
    .....
}

function boolean isNullOrEmpty(Object obj) {
   ...
}

function Object getValueFromFact(Object obj) {
   ....
}
```

I restart my tomcat, run this unit test, but one thread failed, the error was :

`org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: loader (instance of  org/drools/rule/JavaDialectRuntimeData$PackageClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "com/icil/sofs/booking/rules/GetValueFromFact"`

'getValueFromFact' is a function which defined in rules file.

then run it again without restart tomcat, there is no error.  then run third time without restart tomcat, there is no error too.

after tried, i found that the 'duplicate class' error only happened at the first time running after restarting tomcat.

i also found that at the first time, 2 threads are execute 'knowldegeSession.execute()' at the "same time", but 2 threads are run 'knowledgeSession.execute()' in sequence at 2nd time and 3rd time.

so why this error 'duplicate class definition' always happened at the first time running after restart tomcat?

and why the error is the function 'getValueFromFact'(this is the 3rd function in rules file) but not the first function 'updateItem'(this is the first function in rules file)?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Because there are multiple threads are running 'execute()', and they are loading functions at the 'same time', so this error thrown out.

When calling 'addKnowledgePackages()', drools will load rules, but the functions may not be loaded at this time, they may be loaded when calling 'execute()'.

After debugging, i found that drools will load functions if rules conditions use mvel expression instead of java expression when calling 'addKnowldegePackages()'.

I am using drools 5.5.0.Final, I cannot upgrade drools to 6.0 at present because 6.0 has big difference.  But I have to figure out a solution as this problem need to be fixed as soon as possible :

Make your code 'addKnowledgePackages()' can be run when tomcat start, e.g. put it in a static block, as well as change your rules to use mvel expression rather than java expression.